# whats the mistake in the onclick line for button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={this.setState({value: 'X'})}>
        {this.state.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i}/>;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Game />);
```

whats the mistake in the onclick line for button ?
For every click, it should display an X in square in which we have clicked but it is not doing that. I am a beginner trying to learn react js. through its tutorials which are given on its official site. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You have to pass `onClick` a callback function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a callback function to `onClick`.

[`codesandbox link`](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-estrela-l8fcfp?file=/src/index.js)

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ value: "X" })
```

instead of

```
onClick={this.setState({value: 'X'})
```